# iOS: Core Data: NSRangeException in simple example

Tags: ios, core-data

I made a simple Core Data Example:

```
NSLog(@"Loading...");
NSURL *modelUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataTest" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl];    
NSManagedObjectContext *objectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"]];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
NSPersistentStore *migratedStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error];
if(migratedStore == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Could not initialize or migrate store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

[objectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

MyQueuedJob *queuedJob = (MyQueuedJob *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyQueuedJob" inManagedObjectContext:objectContext];
queuedJob.fooBar = @"Test";

[objectContext save:&error];
sleep(2);

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest alloc];
NSEntityDescription *entDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyQueuedJob" inManagedObjectContext:objectContext];
[request setEntity:entDesc];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fooBar" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDesc, nil]];
NSLog(@"fetching jobs...");
NSArray *fetchResults = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"jobs fetched!");
NSLog(@"%@", [fetchResults componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
```

Code of MyQueuedJob.h (generated by Xcode):

```
@interface MyQueuedJob : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fooBar;

@end
```

This example runs perfectly fine in the simulator. But when I run it on my real iPhone 4, it crashes with the following message:

```
2012-02-16 11:06:44.819 CoreDataTest[345:707] Loading...
2012-02-16 11:06:46.937 CoreDataTest[345:707] fetching jobs...
2012-02-16 11:06:46.950 CoreDataTest[345:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

on this line:

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which array is being queried to produce the exception? Enable objective-c exception breakpoints in Xcode, then determine the line of code that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest alloc];
```

You need to init this. Change it to [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

Comment: I don't know why that would be. Ideally it would fail the same way in both places. The iOS simulator is, of course, not a perfect simulation of an actual iOS device. Not all parts of the software are exactly the same. I don't know if the objective-c runtime matches between the iOS simulator and a real iOS device. Certain aspects of iOS hardware are entirely faked in the simulator (for example, CoreLocation, device rotation, and device shaking).